# Adding twitter-bootstrap-rails with an existing rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use twitter-bootstrap-rails with an existing rails application and getting the following error when i refreshed the page.

no such file to load -- less
  (in /app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)

Extracted source (around line #5):

```
2: <html>
3: <head>
4:   <title>Tracker</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
```

any idea what I am doing wrong? 
thanks

Answer (score 11):

In my case, only re-starting the rails server did not do the trick. I had to do following things to fix the problem.

**1.** I needed to install the missing gems first. I added following lines to my Gemfile :

```
  gem "therubyracer"
  gem "less-rails"
```

Then in console I ran:

```
bundle install
```

**2.** Lastly, I had to **re-start my rails server**.

After all these steps, twitter bootstrap started working with my rails app. Hope this helps someone who faces the same trouble that I did !

Answer (score 1):

In some case, you have not installed therubyracer.

add

```
#gem 'therubyracer' , '= 0.10.2'
```

to your Gemfile and

```
#bundle install
```

may resolve this problem.
(In my case, I could not make the rubyracer 0.11.0,
so I designated 0.10.2)

If you have not installed libv8, you have to exec

```
#gem install libv8 --version=3.11.8.3
```

or something like this before hand.

Comment: I tried all of these and still had to add `gem 'less-rails'`, in case anyone else runs into this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by replacing the stylesheet_link_tag to bootstrap_and_overrides. However, I am using devise for authentication and twitter-bootstrap-rails, I think is messes up the devise user model because none of the logout or sign in functions work.

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to get this to work by replacing 'application' with 'bootstrap_and_overrides' in the stylesheet_link_tag tag of the layout template, per sdurg4's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Using rails 3.2.13:

After I installed the 3 gems (therubyracer / less-rails / twitter-bootstrap-rails) I replaced this line   *= require twitter/bootstrap with *= require bootstrap_and_overrides in application.css.

From the github updating guide:

> > This file imports Bootstrap and responsive styles for you (Responsive module is separated.)
> >     https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/wiki/Upgrading-Guide